# Converting Microsoft Office documents and PDF documents to image file with Java

Tags: java

In my current project, I need to convert Microsoft Office documents and PDF documents to image file with Java. Is there any open source Java library for that. And if so, which is the most reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache PDFBox for PDF and Apache POI for converting Microsoft office documents.

[Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try using [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) .

It is a open source project. The Java OpenDocument Converter, converts documents between different office formats.

Picked from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437394/java-library-for-converting-word-documents-to-pdfs-or-images)

Comment: When i check supported formats i don't see any image extension. And also JODConverter need to run OpenOffice as a service in background. can i get another.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [docx4j](https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to convert the Office Docs to PDF.